# Objective C Regex for tokenizing a sentence

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have some text in the following format:

```
{{st1:[[word1]]-[[word2]]s [[word1]] [[word3]]}} {{st2:[[word2]] [[word3]] [[word1]]-[[word4]]s.}}
```

I want to filter out sentences (signature `{{st[0-9]: }}`) which contain the given word (signature `[[word]]` ). Hence, if I am searching for `[[word1]]` , the output should be

```
{{st1:[[word1]]-[[word2]]s [[word1]] [[word3]]}} 
{{st2:[[word2]] [[word3]] [[word1]]-[[word4]]s.}}
```

while if I am searching for `[[word4]]` , the output should be

```
{{st2:[[word2]] [[word3]] [[word1]]-[[word4]]s.}}
```

I have written the following code so far, but cant achieve the above. Please help me to correct it.

```
NSString* aString = @"{{st1:[[word1]]-[[word2]]s [[word1]] [[word3]]}} {{st2:[[word2]] [[word3]] [[word1]]-[[word4]]s.}}";
NSString *regexString   = @"\\{\\{st[1-9]:.*(word).*\\}\\}";
for(NSString *match in [aString componentsMatchedByRegex:regexString])
    NSLog(@"%@", match);
```

I am using RegexKitLite , but am open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current regex is that the `.*` will match the `}}` at the end of a sentence, you need to make sure that the inner part of your regex can never proceed past a `}}`, here is one way to do this:

```
\\{\\{st[1-9]:[^}]*(word)[^}]*\\}\\}
```

If a single closing curly brace is a valid character for part of a word it gets a little more complicated, but you should be able to replace the `[^}]*` with `(\}?[^}])*` or `(?:(?!\}\}).)*`.